# CSS Shorthand available?

Tags: css

Let's say I have the following markup.

```
<div class="parent1">
    <div class="inner1"></div>
    <div class="inner2"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent2">
    <div class="inner1"></div>
    <div class="inner2"></div>
</div>
```

If I only want to style inner1 of parent1 then I can do something as follows.

```
.parent1 .inner1{}
```

However if I want to specify different styles for each of the inner containers then I have to write .parentx in each statement.  So my question is can I nest my css statements? The logic would resemble the following:

```
.parent1{
    .inner1{}
    .inner2{}
}
.parent2{
    .inner1{}
    .inner2{}
}
```

Comment: Take a look at SASS - http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: SASS or LESS. These two (and there are probably others) add logic, mixins and the ability to nest (heirachical css). They are excellent additions but do require a bit of setup and new learning of course

Comment: Both are good ... but I have used SASS more - only cos i came accross it before less ... once you've done all you're definitions and setting stuff up it does save a lot of work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS itself does not allow nesting. However, clever guys these days came up with a concept of pre-compiled CSS, such as SASS, LESS etc.

http://lesscss.org/

For example, in LESS something like this is allowed:

```
#header {
  h1 {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  p { font-size: 12px;
    a { text-decoration: none;
      &:hover { border-width: 1px }
    }
  }
}
```

But if you are stuck with raw CSS, then what @Brian suggested in his answer would be the best option:

```
.parent1 .inner1,
.parent1 .inner2 {
  /*styles*/
}
.parent2 .inner1,
.parent2 .inner2 {
  /*styles*/
}
```

Comment: I found LESS better than SASS so +1 for bigging up LESS ;)

Comment: Never really played much with SASS, but LESS became my friend instantly.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is:

```
.parent1 .inner1,
.parent1 .inner2 {
  /*styles*/
}
.parent2 .inner1,
.parent2 .inner2 {
  /*styles*/
}
```

This will apply the styles to the 2 lots accordingly.

Comment: This still requires me to write out each parentx. I'm lazy :)

Comment: So are we all, but rules are rules :)

Comment: @Brian - he can use LESS or SASS which will allow him to code like he wants but will require an extra step to compile the LESS/SASS into normal css (unless he uses a server side 'on-the-fly SASS/LESS compiler. I know asp.net has one as have most major platforms)

Comment: So basically :) spend a couple of days getting familiar with Less/SASS ... or do it the slightly long (but only) shorthand-ish way :)

Comment: @Brian - Spend 3-4 hours mastering it and every day you use it creating large style schemes you will save + saving refactoring + creating cleaner stylesheets + creating themeable style sheets (you have variables and mixins).

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't give us much in the way of reducing keystrokes.  This is why projects like [Less](http://lesscss.org/) and [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) were created.

Answer (score 0):

The shorthand you've described there would be nice, but sadly is not a feature of CSS. The selectors are always read right to left, so `.parent1 .inner1` instructs the browser to "find all items with an **inner1** class, then loops through those to find the one(s) that are also a **parent1** class.

In your specific example, you might consider one of the following options:

1. If your styles are specific to a single item (the first div within **parent1**), consider giving that item an **id="foo"** and then refer to it as `#foo` in your CSS.
2. If you don't want to do that, use the `>` (child) operator to define rules like this...

   `.inner1 > .parent1`

   This applies rules for the `.inner1` divs that are directly descended from a `.parent1` block.

Hope that helps.